# Error 405 using nodemailer and local server

Tags: next.js, error-handling, nodemailer

I keep getting error 405 while trying to post the form. I've looked over the code and it seems like everything is correct. Console is showing

POST http://localhost:3000/api/sendEmail net::ERR_ABORTED 405 (Method Not Allowed)

This is my code

OrderForm.js

```
const res = await fetch("/api/sendEmail", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(order),
    });

    if (res.status === 200) {
      router.refresh();
      router.push("/custom-order/order-submitted");
    } else {
      console.error("Failed to submit form:", res.statusText);
    }
  };
```

api/sendEmail/route.js

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const username = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BURNER_USERNAME;
  const password = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BURNER_PASSWORD;
  const myEmail = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PERSONAL_EMAIL;

  if (req.method === "POST") {
    // Extract form data from the request body
    const { name, email, message } = req.body;

    // Create a Nodemailer transporter
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", {
      // Configure your email provider here
      host: "sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io",
      port: 2525,

      auth: {
        user: username,
        pass: password,
      },
    });
```

I've tried changing the email providers as I had it as the iCloud SMTP but realized that the problem is there's an error posting but I truly don't see where